# Perfect forwarding not picking up method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I am getting a SFINAE error with the following code as it will not use the template. I am trying to perfect forward the args in as the result. Any ideas anyone.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "constants.h"


namespace perfectforwarding
{
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr auto maximum(T&& a, U&& b) -> decltype( (a > b) ? std::forward(a) : std::forward(b))
    {
        return (a > b) ? std::forward(a) : std::forward(b);
    }
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::cout << "Created count is: " << created_count << std::endl;

    auto const result = perfectforwarding::maximum(5,6.0);

    std::cout << "The maximum of 5 and 6: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Blair

Comment: I don't think you will get what you want from that piece of code. The expression inside the `decltype` is the evaluation of the ternary operator, and the ternary operator yields an expression that is the *common type* of the two alternatives. Basically your template is the same as `template <typename T, typename U> auto maximum(T&&x,T&&y) -> std::common_type(std::forward(x),std::forward(y))`. That is, it will **not** pick the type of the argument whose value is *larger*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::forward` is a template, and you need to provide the type argument explicitly if you want it to work properly. This is how your `maximum` function template should be rewritten:

```
template<class T, class U>
constexpr auto maximum(T&& a, U&& b) -> 
    decltype( (a > b) ? std::forward<T>(a) : std::forward<U>(b))
{
    return (a > b) ? std::forward<T>(a) : std::forward<U>(b);
}
```

This is how the `std::forward` utility is defined:

```
template<class T> 
T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& a) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<S&&>(a);
}
```

The expression `typename remove_reference<T>::type` makes this a non-deduced context, which explains why type deduction fails if you do not explicitly provide the type argument `T`.

Comment: @BlairDavidson: I know the feeling :-)

Comment: Removed the absurd comment... I need to learn how to read (and read the whole answer :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's fine, happened to me several times already ;-)